Conditional text in Word?
Been a number of years since I did this in InDesign, but I had a document where you could hide/show conditional text that had been categorized based on your needs. I'm looking to do similar in Word.
I have a simple Word template file that I want to use for meeting AGENDAS and meeting MINUTES, but need to be able to toggle between the two for text in the document header, footer, and a single paragraph within. Is there a way to achieve this in Word? In InDesign, I believe I would "hide" AGENDA and "unhide" MINUTES, and the text would change.

Word (and obviously also Outlook) may have evaluated formulas in documents:

Insert a formula in a table cell
Select the table cell where you want your result. If the cell is not empty, delete its contents.

On the Table Tools, Layout tab, in the Data group, click Formula.

Use the Formula dialog box to create your formula. You can type in the Formula box, select a number format from the Number Format list,

and paste in functions and bookmarks using the Paste Function and
Paste Bookmark lists.

Right click > Update or hitting F9 recalculates the displayed result.
Ref and more:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-a-formula-in-a-word-or-outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27
